# for loop and dplyr package

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr

My data looks like this:

```
  died   pre_died zipid1 zipid2 zipid3 zipid4 zipid5 zipid6 zipid7 zipid8 zipid9 zipid10 zipid11 zipid12 zipid13
1    1 0.03070181      1      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0       0       0       0       0
2    0 0.13301922      1      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0       0       0       0       0
3    1 0.87192980      1      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0       0       0       0       0
4    0 0.01805484      1      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0       0       0       0       0
5    0 0.02586771      1      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0       0       0       0       0
6    0 0.02476175      1      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0       0       0       0       0
```

I want to sum the died var for each zipid from zipid1 to zipid30. My current code is like this

```
collapse <- data %>%
    summarize(
      outc_n1 = sum(died[zipid1=="1"], na.rm = T),
      outc_n2 = sum(died[zipid2=="1"], na.rm = T),
      outc_n3 = sum(died[zipid3=="1"], na.rm = T),
      ...
    )
```

The zipid ranges from zipid1-zipid30, how can I write a for loop instead of typing the same line for 30 times?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `summarize_at`, and then use `vars(matches(...))` to choose which columns to summarize:

```
data %>% summarise_at(vars(matches('zipid')), funs(outc = sum(died[. == '1'], na.rm=T)))

#  zipid1_outc zipid2_outc zipid3_outc zipid4_outc zipid5_outc zipid6_outc zipid7_outc zipid8_outc
#1           2           0           0           0           0           0           0           0
#  zipid9_outc zipid10_outc zipid11_outc zipid12_outc zipid13_outc
#1           0            0            0            0            0
```

Answer (score 2):

Another **dplyr** option:

```
data <- gather(data, zip, value, -died, -pre_died) %>%
    filter(value == 1) %>%
    group_by(zip) %>%
    summarize(sum_died = sum(died, na.rm = T))
```

Comment: Not very familiar with the gather function, I think it converts zipid from wide format to long format? the reason why I did not use `group_by` is that one patient can have zipid = 1 for more than one region(zipid1 == 1 and zipid3 = =1). So I need to count them twice.

Comment: That should still be fine using the code above. If a row has multiple `zipid == 1` columns, `gather`ing the data frame will duplicate the `died` and `pre_died` values for those rows.